# Using a constructor never defined for the class

Tags: c++, class, constructor

I can't figure out what constructor is used to create `e`:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {

public:
A() {cout<<"DEFAULT CTOR\n";}
A(int) {cout<<"A(int) CTOR\n";}

A(const A &) {cout<<"COPY CTOR\n";}
A(A &&) {cout<<"MOVE CTOR\n";}

A & operator= (const A &) {cout<<"COPY =\n";}
A & operator= (A &&) {cout<<"MOVE =\n";}


A operator+ () {A a; cout<<"operator+\n"; return a;}



void funct () { A e(+*this); }


};

int main () {

A a;
a.funct();

}
```

Why is `e` not constructed with the copy constructor? Who is actually constructing it?

The output is:

```
DEFAULT CTOR
DEFAULT CTOR
operator+
```

Comment: Your `operator=` functions don't return...

Comment: Yes, my bad. But even if the returned the output would be the same.